# Is it true that an Ito integral is Gaussian if and only if the integrand is deterministic?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis, stochastic-differential-equations

It is a well known results that if $f$ is deterministic and Ito integrable, then $\int_0^t f(s) dB(s)$ is Gaussian. Is the converse true? If $\int_0^t f(s) dB(s)$ is Gaussian, then is $f$ deterministic?

Comment: the second integral should be wrt to the brownian motion $B(s)$ and not wrt to $s$, right?

Comment: @RScrlli yes, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. By the Lévy criterion, 
$$
W(t) = \int_0^t \operatorname{sign} B(s) dB(s)
$$
is a standard Wiener process.